# Find the irreducible factors of the polynomial $x^3 + 5x^2 + 2x + 6 \in \mathbb{Z}_7 [ x ]$ .

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

> Find the irreducible factors of the polynomial $$x^3 + 5x^2 + 2x + 6 \in \mathbb{Z}_7 [ x ]$$

I am having trouble understanding irreducible factors for my algebra module and have an exam next week. If any one could help me understand this sample question, I would be so grateful

Comment: Have you checked for zeros in $\Bbb{Z}_7$? Only seven values to test...(and one obvious root)

Comment: Please take the previous comment as a suggestion. We require you to explain what you have problems with. Looking for zeros is the first thing to try when factoring polynomials, so do that.

Comment: As it is phrased the question looks like a copy/pasted homework problem, which you are not going to get help with (because we don't know what exactly you have trouble with). Undoubtedly it was not your intention to attempt to outsource HW. In that case following my suggestion will help to dispel such thoughts.

Comment: Thank for the tip! Understanding how to go about answering these questions was unclear to me but this will help thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the comments, there are only seven values to test in $\mathbb{Z}_7$. Testing the value 1, we get:

$$(1^3 + 5 \cdot 1^2 + 2 \cdot 1 + 6)\,mod\,7 = 14\,mod\,7 = 0$$

If we do the same for the values 3 and 5, we get 0 as well. Indeed, in $\mathbb{Z}_7$:

$$(x-1)(x-3)(x-5) = x^3 - 9 x^2 + 23 x - 15 = x^3 + 5 x^2 + 2 x + 6$$

Comment: Oh so the irreducible factors are the numbers which give you 0 such as 1,3 and 5?

Comment: The irreducible factors are $x-1$, $x-3$ and $x-5$, as these cannot be reduced to a multiplication of two factors of a lower degree.

Comment: Thank you so much! A great help

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted by clicking the accept button on the left.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Over a field, a cubic polynomial either is irreducible or has a factor of degree one, that is, a root.

Or:

$$
x^3 + 5x^2 + 2x + 6 
= x^3 - 2x^2 + 2x -1
= x^3 - 2x^2 + x + x-1
= x(x^2 - 2x + 1) + x-1
= x(x-1)^2 + x-1
=(x-1)(x(x-1)+1)
=(x-1)(x^2-x+1)
=(x-1)(x^2+6x+8)
=(x-1)(x+2)(x+4)
=(x-1)(x-3)(x-5)
$$